# Find event on cell click Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Calender Control, which is populated with events on Page_Load. When a user clicks on a cell I want to find the events in that cell and then populate a Text Area with the information.

I can get the Click Event to happen when they click on a cell but I don't know how to get the event and display in a Text Area in Javascript.

```
<DayPilot:DayPilotMonth CssClassPrefix="bsimplexcalender" 
    OnCommand="calender_control_Command" 
    ContextMenuID="menu" 
    EventRightClickHandling="ContextMenu" 
    EventRightClickJavaScript="select(e)" 
    BubbleID="DayPilotBubble1" 
    ClientObjectName="dpm" 
    runat="server" 
    ID="calender_control" 
    Theme="bsimplexcalender" 
    HeightSpec="Auto" Height="0" 
    MinCellHeight="63" 
    DataStartField="start" 
    DataEndField="end" 
    DataTextField="name" 
    DataValueField="id" 
    OnBeforeEventRender="calender_control_BeforeEventRender"
    TimeRangeSelectedHandling="JavaScript" 
    TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript="''THIS IS THE CLICK EVENT I NEED TO FIND EVENT AND DISPLAY HERE" />
```

Comment: You have to get it from a database...

Comment: Not familiar with DayPilot, but if it's your click event, you can write code in that event to populate that text area.  If it's something that needs to be more dynamic you should be able to use inline asp.net to put a variable in place of your caps.

Comment: @csanonymus It populates on page load but i dont want to go back to the server side to get the event.

Comment: @RandomUs1r How can i find the event in that cell and display into another textbox though?

Comment: @user3129331 I know..That's why you have to use Ajax

Comment: @csanonymus Do you have any example code that you could supply please?

Comment: @user please provide more details on how you're populating TimeRangeSelectedJavaScript

Answer (score 0):

This code might help :

**For JavaScript :**

```
function loadCalendarEvent(day) {  //call this function when table cell is clicked
//in var day pass the day clicked
            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    //just received the answer from server so do something with it here
                }

            }
            var url; //link to php file
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/json"); //change Content-Type to what you need
            xmlhttp.send(day);
        }
```

**For PHP :**

```
<?php
$ClientData = file_get_contents('php://input'); //day variable is stored here
//query database for event and save it to some variable
echo $thatVariable;
?>
```

If you want me to explain more, leave a comment...